# Reactjs Express App -Heroku Push Error : The 'yarnPath' could not be read from the 'yarnrc.yml' file

Tags: reactjs, express, heroku, heroku-cli

I had deployed a website I am working which is a Reactjs Express App to Heroku. It has deployed for 3 weeks now. But after making some changes to app recently I am not able to push the code to heroku. I am encountering an error when doing a push.

```
$ git push heroku master
Enumerating objects: 912, done.
Counting objects: 100% (912/912), done.
Delta compression using up to 8 threads
Compressing objects: 100% (725/725), done.
Writing objects: 100% (742/742), 27.42 MiB | 2.69 MiB/s, done.
Total 742 (delta 160), reused 30 (delta 8), pack-reused 0
remote: Compressing source files... done.
remote: Building source:
remote:
remote: -----> Building on the Heroku-20 stack
remote: -----> Using buildpack: heroku/nodejs
remote: -----> Node.js app detected
remote:
remote: -----> Creating runtime environment
remote:
remote:        NPM_CONFIG_LOGLEVEL=error
remote:        USE_YARN_CACHE=true
remote:        NODE_VERBOSE=false
remote:        NODE_ENV=production
remote:        NODE_MODULES_CACHE=false
remote:
remote: -----> Build failed
remote:  !     The 'yarnPath' could not be read from the 'yarnrc.yml' file
remote:
remote:       It looks like 'yarnrc.yml' is missing the 'yarnPath' value, which is needed
remote:       to identify the location of yarn for this build.
remote:
remote:       To regenerate 'yarnrc.yml' with the 'yarnPath' value set, make sure Yarn 2
remote:       is installed on your local machine and set the version in your project
remote:       directory with:
remote:
remote:        $ yarn set version berry
remote:
remote:       Read more at the Yarn docs: https://yarnpkg.com/getting-started/install#per-project-install
remote:
remote:        https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/nodejs-support
remote:
remote:  !     Push rejected, failed to compile Node.js app.
remote:
remote:  !     Push failed
remote:  !
remote:  ! ## Warning - The same version of this code has already been built: 21afbb1f965651a191a2a03c3d0047685d8c76fc
remote:  !
remote:  ! We have detected that you have triggered a build from source code with version 21afbb1f965651a191a2a03c3d0047685d8c76fc
remote:  ! at least twice. One common cause of this behavior is attempting to deploy code from a different branch.
remote:  !
remote:  ! If you are developing on a branch and deploying via git you must run:
remote:  !
remote:  !     git push heroku <branchname>:main
remote:  !
remote:  ! This article goes into details on the behavior:
remote:  !   https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/duplicate-build-version
remote:
remote: Verifying deploy...
remote:
remote: !       Push rejected to jithin-career.
remote:
To https://git.heroku.com/jithin-career.git
 ! [remote rejected] master -> master (pre-receive hook declined)
error: failed to push some refs to 'https://git.heroku.com/jithin-career.git'
```

I have been trying to find a solution to this for some time. Some of the solutions which was mentioned didn't work for me. Can anyone please help me this issue?

Comment: Git itself isn't involved in this error. Git is just a delivery driver here, taking your commit to Heroku, and then bringing Heroku's error messages back to you. This is a Heroku issue.

Comment: Having same issue, has anyone been able to resolve this

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem.
Here is the solution.

1. locally, run the following command

```
yarn set version berry
```

2. activate Zero-Install in .gitignore

```
.yarn/*
!.yarn/cache
!.yarn/releases
!.yarn/plugins
!.yarn/sdks
!.yarn/versions
```

or Deactivate Zero-Install

```
.pnp.*
.yarn/*
!.yarn/patches
!.yarn/plugins
!.yarn/releases
!.yarn/sdks
!.yarn/versions
```

3. `yarn install` and apply instllation.
4. Commit all changes to git repogitory.
5. `git push heroku main`

For more information, please refer to the official manual page.

https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/migrating-to-yarn-2#make-changes-to-source-code